# Node.JS Schema.pre('save) is not changing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api, web, bcrypt

I'm making user authorization system and want to hash password before save it to DB. To reach this i use bcrypt-nodejs.
The question in title above;

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { 
         type: String,
         unique: true,
         required: true,
    },
    username: {
         type: String,
         unique: true,
         required: true
    },
    password: { 
         type: String,
         unique: true,
         required: true
    }
});

userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    })
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the solution for your problem:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique:true,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', function() {
  console.log(this.password);
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password);
  console.log(this.password);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Code that I used to run the solution:

```
exports.create = async function () {
  let user = new User({
    email : 'test@test.com',
    username: 'new username',
    password: '123abc'
  });

  return await user.save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};
```

Your first problem is that you can not use **arrow function** in this type of method: [Same Error Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365038/this-is-undefined-in-a-mongoose-pre-save-hook)

Second problem, is that you need to call the **bcrypt.hashSync** method, if you don‘t want to handle Promises.

And one observation about your schema, all the fields are unique. This attribute **unique:true** will create a index in the database, and you won't find the user by password. Here the moongose documentation: [Moogose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

> A common gotcha for beginners is that the unique option for schemas is not a validator. It's a convenient helper for building MongoDB unique indexes. See the FAQ for more information.